# Rich text editor with standalone apps under Sitecore web root

Tags: asp.net, iis, sitecore, sitecore6

I've been trying to configure a standalone ASP.Net application beneath a Sitecore web root (more or less as outlined here: http://sitecoreblog.alexshyba.com/2009/05/standalone-apps-under-sitecore-web-root.html).  It's almost successful in that the virtual directory runs, but in the /sitecore folder, the rich text editor no longer works.  Here is the error it throws:

'~/Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd' is missing in web.config. RadScriptManager requires a HttpHandler registration in web.config. Please, use the control Smart Tag to add the handler automatically, or see the help for more information: Controls > RadScriptManager.

It works fine when I revert back to the original configuration.
Does anyone know how to properly configure this?

**More info (1):**
So, in the sitecore web.config, at the root, I added:
location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false" above the sitecore, system.webserver, and system.web nodes.  The non-sitecore app I was attempting to run works great when I do this, but it somehow creates the Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd I mention above, in the /sitecore folder, mostly when using the rich text box.

**More info (2):** This happens when I make these changes to the web.config in the sitecore root.  While attempting to fix the problem, I did make a few changes to the web.config files in the /sitecore folder (including deleting them). but it made no difference.  I've since restored the /sitecore folder to it's original configuration.

The standalone app is running as a separate app, immediately off the root, so: http://mysitecoresite/mystandaloneapp.

Comment: Where is your standalone application located related to the webroot ? Also are you sure you haven`t applied any changes to the Sitecore web.config ?

Comment: What are the changes you made to config?

Comment: Added to the original post.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. After much searching, this fixed it for me (using v7.2 rev 140228): http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/scriptmanager/troubleshooting/overview#telerikwebuiwebresourceaxd-is-missing-in-webconfig-radscriptmanager-requires-a-httphandler-registration-in-webconfig

You have to set the EnableHandlerDetection property where it is declared on the Sitecore .aspx pages. I found it on EditorWindow.aspx and EditorPage.aspx.

```
<telerik:RadScriptManager ID="RadScriptManager" runat="server" EnableHandlerDetection="false"></telerik:RadScriptManager>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It works like a charm. I know this is an old post but some body will definitely benefit from your answer. The exact location of these files are sitecore\shell\Controls\Rich Text Editor